# How to install different files for different Visual Studio versions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm creating an extension that install native visualizations ([natvis](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2)), but each new version of VS contain new features in natvis format.

I want create one extension that works for all VS versions If it were possible  install different natvis files depending on the version of VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Create two natvis files one for VS2012 and the other for VS2013 and VS2015.

If you want to implement a [visualization service](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Writing-graphical-debugger-a17e3d75#content), then do the following, otherwise skip to deployment.

You need to define two interfaces with different GUIDs and implementations. Use the UIVisualizer XML element in the natvis files to assign the GUID of the interface that corresponds to the natvis file. Now in the Initialize method of the VSPackage, include this piece of code:

```
appObject = (DTE2)GetService(typeof(DTE));
if(appObject.Version == "11.0")
{
    // Register the VS2012 visualization service using ((IServiceContainer)this).AddService().
}
else
{
    // Register the VS2013/VS2015 visualization service.
}
```

To deploy the package, create two VSIX containers that are identical in every way except that the first includes one natvis file and the other includes the other natvis file. To include a natvis file, add an `Asset` element to the VSIX manifest:

```
<PackageManifest ...>
  . 
  . 
  . 
  <Assets> 
    <Asset Type="NativeVisualizer" Path="natvis.xml"/>  
  </Assets> 
</PackageManifest>
```

In this way you will be having one extension but two VSIX containers.

Comment: Thank you, but Visual Studio Gallery doesn't allow upload several VSIX files for one extension. Therefore, I will have to publish a separate extension for each version of VS.

Comment: @KindDragon The problem is how to deploy the natvis files to the corresponding version of VS. One way is to create different VSIX containers. Another is to embed that natvis files as resources in an MSI installer and copy them to the corresponding folder (%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Visual Studio [2012|2013|2015]\Visualizers\) when the extension is installed. Yet another way is to create the natvis files when the extension is loaded for the first time in Visual Studio. When the debugging session starts, VS will automatically pick up the right natvis.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with msi installer

Comment: @KindDragon It's been a while, has your problem been resolved?